# Looking for recommendations and advice for DB project with subscriptions

Tags: content-management-system, keystonejs

I have a client who has a bunch of data that she wants to put into a database and have it searchable and filterable for paying members only, ideally on a subscription basis (monthly, 3months, yearly).

I've done a couple of projects using KeystoneJS, so my first thought is to build out the DB/CMS in keystone and create a small front-end application in NextJS for registering users and subscriptions powered by Stripe.

Does anyone else have any experience building something like this? Any recommendations or suggestions? I know I could obviously do something like this in WordPress, but I prefer JavaScript. Although I could be convinced if anyone has a compelling argument!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm on the Keystone dev team so possibly biased   That said, Keystone does sounds like a good fit for your project.

One project I've worked in particular sounds close to what you're doing – a large website with Stripe-based subscriptions that unlock additional functionality. The site has over a million registered users, 30k of which are on paid subscriptions. Keystone manages all the data, the admin UI (used by staff) and most of the API generation. The dev work was mostly to build out the public, Next.js frontend. The solution and general architecture has worked well.

You mention search and filtering. The GraphQL API Keystone generates is extremely flexible in terms of filtering but doesn't currently offer any full-text search functionality (though, it is planned). Depending on your exact requirements you might need to go beyond the basic configuration. In the project described above, we flattened some of the content out behind the scenes, added some [full-text indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) and [extended the GraphQL schema](https://keystonejs.com/docs/apis/config#extend-graphql-schema) with some search queries.

Whether it's this kind of extension, custom field types, hooks or customisation of the Admin UI, Keystone has a lot of "escape hatches". It very much tries to create a framework that guides common solutions while also helping developers extend and build on it as a platform (without getting in the way).

Comment: Thank you so much! I do think this will work really great for my project.   Do you have any examples of extending the Admin UI to add descriptions under the labels in create/edit mode?

Comment: @weenz, best to take up that kind of question in the community slack: https://community.keystonejs.com/